# jQuery $(this) instead of multiple ids

Tags: jquery, this

I have 9 similar code blocks that toggle and add/remove class on click.
It works if I use ids like this

```
$('#js-flip-1').toggle(
            function() {
                $('#js-flip-1 .card').addClass('flipped');
            },
            function() { 
                $('#js-flip-1 .card').removeClass('flipped');
            }
);
$('#js-flip-2').toggle(
            function() {
                $('#js-flip-2 .card').addClass('flipped');
            },
            function() { 
                $('#js-flip-2 .card').removeClass('flipped');
            }
);
```

But there should be some cleaner solution, I thought of $(this) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.flip').toggle(
                function() {
                     $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped');
                },
                function() { 
                     $(this).find('.card').removeClass('flipped');
                }
            );

});
```

Or mb toggleClass

```
$( ".flip" ).click(function() {
  $( ".card" ).toggleClass( "flipped" );
});
```

My current Html structure is like this

```
<div id="js-flip-4" class="flip">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="face front">
                              <img src="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="face back">
                            <h3 class="card-name"><a href=""></a></h3>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div id="js-flip-5" class="flip">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="face front">
                              <img src="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="face back">
                            <h3 class="card-name"><a href=""></a></h3>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Any help and hints are appreciated.

**Solution**

This actually works, dont know what I was doing wrong the first time.

```
        $('.flip').click(
            function() {
                 $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
            }
        );
```

Comment: Beware that this version of `toggle` was deprecated in v1.8 and *removed* in v1.9: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Your "simpler" solution should work. and [does for me](http://jsfiddle.net/dhwuL0t6/) (using jQuery v1.8.3, see comment above). (Your "Or mb toggleClass" solution won't work, because you're selecting all `.card` elements. But `$(this).find(".card").toggleClass("flipped")` does: http://jsfiddle.net/dhwuL0t6/1/)

Comment: Oh, it works for me as well now. Need to take a break apparently.
I'm using 1.7 now , but still thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx T.J Crowder, this works

```
    $('.flip').click(
        function() {
             $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        }
    );
```